# Программа должна выводить значения функции и искать минимальное, максимальное и среднее арифметическое.Но почему то тормозит после первых 6 значений

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double y,ymin,ymax,ymiddle,x;
    int i,j,N;
    j={0};
    N=(1.55-1.05)/0.05;
    float yo[N];
    for (x=0.05;x<=1.55;x=x+0.05)
    {
        y=pow(x,(7/3))+3/x-4*pow(x,6)+4/(pow(x,5));
        yo[j]=y;
        j++;
    }
    ymin=yo[0];
    ymax=yo[1];
    for (i=1;i<(N-1);i++)
    {
        ymiddle++;
        if (yo[i]<ymin)
        {
            ymin=yo[i];
        }
        else if (yo[i]>ymax)
        {
            ymax=yo[i];
        }
    }
    ymiddle=ymiddle/N;
    std::cout<<"ymin="<<ymin<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"ymax="<<ymax<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"ymiddle="<<ymiddle<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**ошибка 1:**

у вас

`N=(1.55-1.05)/0.05;`

т.е. `N = 10`, но массив вы заполняете начиная с 0.05

```
for (x=0.05;x<=1.55;x=x+0.05){
```

т.е. 30 шагов, 20 из которых уходит вне диапазона массива и что там за жесть происходит и на что влияет - предсказать сложно

**ошибка 2:**

начальное значение для переменной `ymiddle` вы нигде не задали, но что-то с переменной делаете

```
ymiddle++;
```

в результате значение может быть непредсказуемым и уж точно не тем, которое вы ожидаете

**ошибка 3:**

вот так:

```
ymin=yo[0];
ymax=yo[1];
```

писать нехорошо, потому что исследуемая функция должна быть возрастающей, а если это не так? если бы вы значения случайно генерировали, могло получиться, что `y0[0] > y0[1]`

лучше уж

```
ymin=yo[0];
ymax=yo[0];
```

и плясать дальше с 1 позиции

**ошибка 4:**

вот такой код:

```
if (yo[i]<ymin){ymin=yo[i];}
else if (yo[i]>ymax){ymax=yo[i];}
```

неправильно обрабатывает ситуацию, если `yo[i] < ymin` и `yo[i] > ymax` и тесно завязан с ошибкой 3

лучше уж писать

```
if (yo[i]<ymin){ymin=yo[i];}
if (yo[i]>ymax){ymax=yo[i];}
```

**ошибка 5:**

в таком коде

```
for (i=1;i<(N-1);i++){
```

из рассмотрения выпадает последняя (правая) точка

надо

```
for (i=1;i<N;i++){
```

**ошибка 5.5:**

в описанном выше коде при определении `ymiddle` (ошибка 6 - см. ниже) выпадает из рассмотрения еще и первая (левая) точка

надо уж сделать проход по всем точкам

```
for (i=0;i<N;i++){
```

**ошибка 6:**

с помощью этого кода вы никак не вычислите среднее арифметическое

```
ymiddle++;
```

в идеале вы получите `ymiddle = N`, а в окончательном результате `ymiddle = 1`

надо

```
ymiddle = ymiddle + yo[i];
```

Comment: Чочо? Если ymin и ymax правильно инициализированы, то y не может быть одновременно меньше первого и больше второго.

Comment: @bipll, а кто говорит про правильную инициализацию если минимальным считается первый элемент, а максимальным второй

Comment: Ну так ошибка 3. есть, а ощибки 4. нет.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (x=0.05;x<=1.05;x=x+0.05)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас зачем-то подключено `<stdio>`, часть переменных `double`, часть - `float`. Путаетесь - конечные данные при 1.05 или 0.05? При вычислении `N` - старая детская ошибка - столбов на 1 больше, чем промежутков между ними.

И вообще массив не нужен.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double f(double x) {
    return pow(x, (7 / 3)) + 3 / x - 4 * pow(x, 6) + 4 / (pow(x, 5));
    }

int main() {
    double ymin, ymax, ymiddle = 0;
    int N = 0;
    ymin = ymax = f(0.05);

    for (double y, x = 0.05; x <= 1.55 + 0.05 / 2; x += 0.05) {
        N++;
        ymiddle += (y = f(x));

        if (y > ymax) ymax = y;
        else if (y < ymin) ymin = y;
        }

    ymiddle /= N;
    cout << "ymin=" << ymin << endl;
    cout << "ymax=" << ymax << endl;
    cout << "ymiddle=" << ymiddle << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь задать размер только целочисленным типом float yo[N]

Comment: `N` и так целочисленный